# factory contract reverts

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am trying to create a factory contract, which I call DAG:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
import "./Agent.sol";

    contract DAG {
    
        address[] agents;
    
        function createDAG() public returns (address) {
            // create root agent
            address[] memory parentsOfRoot;
            address rootAddress = createAgent(parentsOfRoot);
    
    
            // create child
            address[] memory parentsOfChild;
            parentsOfChild[0] = rootAddress;
            createAgent(parentsOfChild);
    
            return rootAddress;
            
        }
        function createAgent(address[] memory _parents) public returns(address) {
            Agent agent = new Agent(_parents);
            agents[agents.length - 1] = address(agent);
            return address(agent);        
        }
    }
```

It is meant to make something like a connected list of Agents.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Agent {

    address[] parents;

    constructor(
        address[] memory _parents
    ){
        parents = _parents;
    }

    function getParents() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return parents;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I call `createDAG` in the RemixIDE, I get the following error:

> transact to DAG.createDAG pending ...  transact to DAG.createDAG
> errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note:
> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

Can anyone help me understand why I am unable to call `createDAG`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet is trying to assign into 0th index of the array but this index doesn't exist at that moment. Which throws an "out of bounds" exception.

```
address[] memory parentsOfChild; // 0 items
parentsOfChild[0] = rootAddress; // trying to assign the first item (index 0)
```

It's currently (v0.8) not possible to resize in-memory arrays, so you'll need to initialize the array with an already predefined length.

```
address[] memory parentsOfChild = new address[](1); // 1 empty item
parentsOfChild[0] = rootAddress;
```

---

Then you're going to run into another logical error. Function `createAgent()` is also trying to assign a value to an "out of bounds" index.

When the `agents` array is empty, this snippet is trying to assign into index -1.

```
agents[agents.length - 1] = address(agent);
```

If you want to add a new item to the `agents` array, you can use the `.push()` member function of the array.

```
// instead of `agents[agents.length - 1] = address(agent);`
agents.push(address(agent));
```